# django run websocket client in background

Tags: python, django

So when I run the WebSocket client I can no longer reach the Django app like I can't connect to `127.0.0.1:8000`, here is the WebSocket file:

```
import websocket, json, pprint
from datetime import datetime


socket = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/manausdt@kline_1m"


def on_message(ws, msg):
    message = json.loads(msg)
    messageData = message['k']

    if messageData['x']:
        # get_data(messageData)
        timestamp = float(messageData['t'])
        symbol = messageData['s']
        interval = messageData['i']
        closeprice = float(messageData['c'])
        openprice = float(messageData['o'])
        highprice = float(messageData['h'])
        lowprice = float(messageData['l'])
        datetime_ob = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1000)

        data = {'timestamp': timestamp, 'symbol': symbol, 'interval': interval, 'closeprice': closeprice,
                'openprice': openprice, 'highprice': highprice, 'lowprice': lowprice, 'datetime_ob': datetime_ob}

        print(data)


def on_open(ws):
    print('Connected!')


def on_error(wsapp, err):
    print("Got a an error: ", err)


def runwss():
    stream = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_error=on_error, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message)
    stream.run_forever()


runwss()
```

And I inited it in `apps` file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ServiceGetDataConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'service_get_data'

    def ready(self):
        import service_get_data.wss
```

And as I said I can't reach `127.0.0.1:8000` anymore so what shall I do in this case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I searched online and ended up with using `Threading` module:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=runwss)
thread.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

You're importing the websocket in your app config's ready() method so your ready method doesn't continue and exit as it suppose to, therefore it's stuck in the websocket infinite loop.

I suggest using a library, that does the heavy lifting of the websockets behind the scenes for you:
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_2.html

Although, if you need a client, you could just connect to it from your frontend and serve the html via django

Comment: isn't `channels` to create your own `WebSocket`? if so then that will not solve my issue because I'm connecting to a `WebSocket` not creating one, and `Although, if you need a client, you could just connect to it from your frontend and serve the html via django` what do you mean? I'm getting data from the `WebSocket` to perform actions upon it how will sending it to the frontend do that?

Comment: Yeah channels is for that and I thought you weren't performing any actions on data before serving it in your frontend. But if your actions are simple enough to calculate and doesn't save data your database, you can always use javascript to do those calculations and display it on your frontend, link I sent you actually has a js that can connect to the websocket, you can check it out there if that satisfies your requirements